# r error: "Error in mkRespMod(fr, REML = REMLpass) : response must be numeric"

Tags: r, icc

I am new to R and trying to use the psych package to run an ICC to compute emotion differentiation. I am getting the following error:

> Error in mkRespMod(fr, REML = REMLpass) : response must be numeric

Here is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(irr)
library(psych)

data_newICC <- data %>%
  psych::ICC(data[list_NE_image], missing = TRUE, lmer = TRUE)
```

The values in the list_NE_image list are all numeric, so unclear where the error is coming from/what is if referring to!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Clearly list all non base R package you use by including the appropriate `library()` calls in your code.

Comment: Thank you! 
Here are the packages: 
library(tidyverse)
library(irr)
library(psych)